# Post content to php via jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm struggling to pass on a simple text from a div to a php post file.
In belows example the variable "first_name" is assigned to an input field, but I'd rather to post the text below.

What would be the correct workaround?

```js
function clickButton() {
  var first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "cases_action.php",
    data: {
      'first_name': first_name
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      alert('Data Send');
      $('#msg').html(html);
    }
  });
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Your first name.."></p>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" name="" value="submit" onclick="return clickButton();">
</form>
<p id="msg"></p>

<p>This text should be passed to cases_action via "first_name" instead of content from the input textbox </p>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Is there a specific issue? Where's the PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"from a div"* ...I see a `<p>` but not a `<div>`. They are different.

Anyway that's just a terminology note.

If you want to get the text from the `<p>` element, then it's simple - just write code to look at that element. Right now you're selecting from the form field in your Javascript, so you just need to change the target.

Give the `<p>` an ID and select from that instead (using `.innerText` because non-form elements don't have a `value`).

Demo (in which I've also assumed you want to change the name of the field you're sending in the AJAX, since it isn't a name anymore:

```js
function clickButton() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text').innerText;
  console.log(text);

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "cases_action.php",
    data: {
      'text': text
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      alert('Data Send');
      $('#msg').html(html);
    }
  });
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-purchase" name="" value="submit" onclick="return clickButton();">
</form>
<p id="msg"></p>

<p id="text">This text should be passed to cases_action via "first_name" instead of content from the input textbox </p>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Yeah I forgot to put the text into a div in my example. How would it work with a div?

Comment: exactly the same way. HTML elements all have exactly the same standard properties such as "innerText", because they all inherit from [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) - which in turn inherits from [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). Some, such as form fields, have extra ones (such as "value"). If you want to do more of this kind of thing it's probably worth studying DOM manipulation in a bit more detail.